# C# collection

Tags: c#, ienumerable

```
int[] mylist = { 2, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> list1 = mylist;
list1.ToList().Add(1);
// why 1 does not get addedto list1??
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why would it?  ToList() generates a new List and the value '1' gets added to it.  Since you don't store the return, the new list then gets tossed when it's out of scope.

ToList() doesn't change the original IEnumerable object list1 or give a new representation (it would be called AsList() if it did).

Comment: IEnumerable<int> newList = list1.ToList().Add(1); // The code you want

Comment: This is like the commonly made first timer mistake with String.Replace().

Comment: Not quite the same mistake as String.Replace(). The string class is immutable and the List is not. So while .Replace() is creating a new string .Add() is actually adding to a List object. But it's the List created from ToList() and not the original array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to :

```
int[] mylist = { 2, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> list1 = mylist;
List<int> lst = list1.ToList();
lst.Add(1);
mylist = lst.ToArray();
```

Comment: Or just "List<int> lst = myList.ToList();". The IEnumerable variable is not needed.

Comment: That's right Hosam, I just appended to his code to make it simpler.